# getting notice if my php session is not set. how to resolve this? (<b>Notice</b>: Undefined index: myname...)

Tags: php, session, exists

```
let varmyname = '<?php echo isset($_SESSION['myname']);?>';

if (varmyname == "") {
     console.log("session not set "); 
     document.getElementById("inputmyname").value="";

} else {
    console.log(" session set")
    document.getElementById("input-myname").value = '<?php echo $_SESSION['myname']; ?>';
}
```

i am getting notice for this line= document.getElementById("input-myname").value = '';
can we ignore this notice? if not then how to solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: did you start the session? `session_start`, here is link: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: `can we ignore this notice` - sure, you can ignore whatever you like.  Do notices exist just for php to have something to do? No.  Do notices exist to point out non-fatal errors in your code which could further down the line become fatal? Yup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isset` returns true or false, and you are assigning this to your variable, so your variable is always set.  Try console logging `varmyname` you should see this.

Therefore your if statement always falls to the else block, as `if (varmyname == "")` is never true, but you are trying to access it on the line you have an error for.

You need to change the condition to check for a value.  You could try the null coalesce operator, e.g

`let varmyname = '<?php echo ($_SESSION['myname']?? '') ;?>';`